# $_POST doesn't work, $_GET does

Tags: php, html, forms

I've got kind of an annoying problem. When I submit the following code using method="post" and looking for the $_POST variable, the code doesn't recognize it. When I switch to method="get" and look for the $_GET variable it works fine. I would prefer not to use Get. Any suggestions? My final code will contain other inputs as well, however, I want the file input to be optional. So I need to process the code only if the file input is actually sent.  Thanks for your help!

```
 //form.html.php
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label id="upload">Select file to upload:
<input type="file" id="upload" name="foobar" /></label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

//index.php
if(isset($_POST['foobar']))
{
//some code
}
```

However, this works fine

```
//form.html.php
<form action="index.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label id="upload">Select file to upload:
<input type="file" id="upload" name="foobar" /></label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

//index.php
if(isset($_GET['foobar']))
{
//some code
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get file, please use [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php), and you must use `post` method.

Comment: isset($_FILES['foobar'] returned true whether or not a file had been uploaded, so I changed it to if(isset($_FILES['foobar']) and $_FILES['foobar']['name'] !="")

Answer (score 1):

You are uploading a file and do not have any inputs other then the "file" type input. Therefore there will not be any $_POST values sent put $_FILES array. And your form needs to have method="post" set.

Check this code out

```
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
```